# javascript if form value a greater than form value b not working

Tags: javascript

javascript

```
function updatesum()
if (document.form.inputheight.value) > (document.form.inputwidth.value) {
document.form.sum1newwidth.value = (document.form.inputheight.value);
} else {
  document.form.sum1newwidth.value = (document.form.inputwidth.value);
}
```

html

```
Enter dimensions<i>(mm)</i>:<br>
Width<input name="inputwidth" id="inputwidth" onChange="updatesum()" class="form-field" type="number" step="1" />x<input name="inputheight" id="inputheight" onChange="updatesum()" class="form-field" type="number" />Height<br/><br/>
New W =<input name="sum1newwidth" readonly class="form-field" type="number" />
```

Not showing the result in `sum1newwidth`, I believe because of something I've done wrong in either the 'greater than' part or if/else part, not sure, help please :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra **'('** and **')'** you have laid out, like so:

```
function updatesum()
{
    if (document.form.inputheight.value > document.form.inputwidth.value) 
    {
        document.form.sum1newwidth.value = document.form.inputheight.value;
    }
    else {
        document.form.sum1newwidth.value = document.form.inputwidth.value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try format code like this

```
function updatesum()
if ((document.form.inputheight.value) > (document.form.inputwidth.value)) {
document.form.sum1newwidth.value = (document.form.inputheight.value);
} else {
  document.form.sum1newwidth.value = (document.form.inputwidth.value);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If format is incorrect, you must update parenthesis like this :

```
function updatesum()
{
    if (document.form.inputheight.value > (document.form.inputwidth.value) 
    {
        document.form.sum1newwidth.value = (document.form.inputheight.value);
    } 
    else 
    {
        document.form.sum1newwidth.value = (document.form.inputwidth.value);
    }
}
```